# Javascript Buttons

Tags: javascript, button

Is it possible to set a button's onclick action to a javascript variable? 
The idea is that we are controlling a table with javascript. Whenever one clicks on a row of that table, we update a javascript variable. That var would be the _GET var for the php script to be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the element you want to be clickable :

```
onclick="setAVariable()"
```

And then add this javascript function in a php file :

```
function setAVariable(){ 
    //dostuff 
    var get = "<?php echo _GET ?>" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myTr.onclick = function () {
    // Make sure you have a keyboard focusable and a non-JS alternative!
    document.forms.myform.elements.myhiddeninput.value = someValue;
}
```